# Leave screen callback React Navigation Tab Navigator

Tags: node.js, react-native, react-navigation

I have a React Navigation Tab Component like this:

```
const RootNavigator=TabNavigator({
Home:{
    screen: Home,
    navigationOptions:{
        tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
            <Icon
                name={focused? 'ios-home':'ios-home-outline'}
                style={{color: '#464646'}}
                size={16}
            />
        )
    }
},
Notifications:{
    screen: Notifications,
    navigationOptions:{
        tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
            <TabNotifications focused={focused} />
        )
    }
}, {});
```

Is there a way to make a callback when leaving a screen?

In this case, I would like to perform a function when I leave the Notifications tab. Such as mark the notifications as seen and remove the badge indicator.

As of now, I am pulling the Notification icon from another component in order to show the number badge.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option is to use [`onNavigationStateChange`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-navigator-overview.html#onnavigationstatechangeprevstate-newstate-action) to check the current change of the navigation and do the action you need to clear notifications etc.

> **onNavigationStateChange(prevState, newState, action)**
>
> Function that gets called every time navigation state managed by the
>   navigator changes. It receives the previous state, the new state of
>   the navigation and the action that issued state change. By default it
>   prints state changes to the console.

Another option is to use [`addListener`](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle). This way you can subscribe to `willFocus`/`didFocus` or `willBlur`/`didBlur`  events and do the action you need.

> **addListener** - *Subscribe to updates to navigation lifecycle*
>
> React Navigation emits events to screen components that subscribe to
>   them:
>
> - `willBlur` - the screen will be unfocused
> - `willFocus` - the screen will focus
> - `didFocus` - the screen focused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)
> - `didBlur` - the screen unfocused (if there was a transition, the transition completed)

*Example from the docs*

```
const didBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
  'didBlur',
  payload => {
    console.debug('didBlur', payload);
  }
);
// Remove the listener when you are done
didBlurSubscription.remove();

// Payload
{
  action: { type: 'Navigation/COMPLETE_TRANSITION', key: 'StackRouterRoot' },
  context: 'id-1518521010538-2:Navigation/COMPLETE_TRANSITION_Root',
  lastState: undefined,
  state: undefined,
  type: 'didBlur',
};
```

Comment: I used the addListener function the this.props.navigation and worked as expected. Thanks!

Comment: which life cycle method remove listener. Please Help.

Comment: @VinodRanga depends on where you subscribed to the listener and your component logic. Most likely you can remove listener on `componentWillUnmount`

Answer (score 4):

For those who want a third option, you could use the `NavigationEvents` component as suggested by the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/2.x/navigation-events.html) to listen to navigations hooks and to whatever you intended to do.

> Edit: This is documentation for React Navigation 2.x, which is no
> longer actively maintained. For up-to-date documentation, see the
> latest version (6.x).

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationEvents } from 'react-navigation';

const MyScreen = () => (
  <View>
    <NavigationEvents
      onWillFocus={payload => console.log('will focus',payload)}
      onDidFocus={payload => console.log('did focus',payload)}
      onWillBlur={payload => console.log('will blur',payload)}
      onDidBlur={payload => console.log('did blur',payload)}
    />
    {/* 
      Your view code
    */}
  </View>
);

export default MyScreen;
```

Comment: Is very nice, it works inside a component too !